# Can this LINQ be more efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a fairly complex linq grouping with some repetition that annoys me, but I haven't been able to reduce it.  Is there any way to avoid getting the list of items with ID=="XYZ" twice?

```
var example = = new GdsObservableCollection<GroupedQueryResults>(
                items.Where(a => a.SubCategory3 != "{template}")
                     .GroupBy(item => item.SubCategory1)
                     .Select(g => new GroupedQueryResults
                                  {
                                     SubCategory = g.Key,
                                     SectionHeader = (g.Count(x => x.Id == "XYZ") > 0) ?
                                     "Category :" +  g.Where(x => x.Id == "XYZ")
                                                     .First().NewValue :
                                     "Item - " + itemNumber
```

...

Comment: `g.Count(...) > 0` can always be made more efficient by using `g.Any(...)` instead. `Count()` necessarily iterates through every element (unless the enumerable happens to be a recognized type with a Count or Length property), but `Any()` can stop as soon as it finds a match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duplicate search for `x.Id == "XYZ"` can be avoided by using `Where` + `Select` + `FirstOrDefault` chain combined with C# null-coalescing operator:

```
SectionHeader = g
    .Where(x => x.Id == "XYZ")
    .Select(x => "Category :" +  x.NewValue)
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? "Item - " + itemNumber
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't say more efficient, but can be a little bit smaller, as you can use predicates inside `Any` and `First`:

```
var example = new GdsObservableCollection<GroupedQueryResults>(
            items.Where(a => a.SubCategory3 != "{template}")
                 .GroupBy(item => item.SubCategory1)
                 .Select(g => new GroupedQueryResults
                              {
                                 SubCategory = g.Key,
                                 SectionHeader = g.Any(x => x.Id == "XYZ") ?
                                 "Category :" +  g.First(x => x.Id == "XYZ").NewValue :
                                 "Item - " + itemNumber
```

Comment: Worth mentioning - the `First` won't be more efficient than the `Where` and then `First` but it does the same in less code and is more readable => better code. `Any` vs. `Count` is more efficient